# I need help reading a user-specified text file into an ArrayList of Strings using Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, methods, arraylist

I am advised to use a while loop the Scanner method hasNextLine() and
in the while loop body, call the Scanner method nextLine(), and add the returned String to the ArrayList of Strings. I am new to Java so please keep that in mind. I'm not exactly sure if this is right, but this is what I have gotten so far:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(""));

    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: Now I'm having trouble on figuring out if this code would read a user specified text file and I'm not sure how to print out what the file says using a method.

Comment: Would I use an if statement to have it read?

Comment: Have you at least tried your code? Is this real code or pseudo-code? What exactly do you want?

Comment: I've tried it, but I get error because the while loop isn't closed. So I am trying to figure out how to print out the file.

Comment: possible duplicate , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file

Comment: What do you mean with `because the while loop isn't closed.`? This code axample is missing a closing `}` for the while loop. Yes. Add it.

Comment: I see what you're saying, @Alexander , but how would I get it to ask the user "Input file name? "

Answer (score 1):

With this code you can:

- prompt a user for a file name.
- read the file line by line using the Scanner class.
- add each line to an ArrayList of Strings.

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Location of file to read
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a filename: ");
        String fileName = x.nextLine();
        File file = new File(fileName);

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        try { 

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                lines.add(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of the e.printStackTrace(); , I've always used the system.out.print(); , should I not use that in this case?

Comment: @JavaNovice If the file is not found, the code above catch an exception and therefore print the stack trace.

Comment: how do I get it to ask the user, "Input file name? "

Comment: Wait, one more question, sorry! For: ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(); it tells me to use the diamond operator instead. and for the Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); it tells me to convert to try with resources. and it also tells me to delete the print stack trace, why?

Comment: @JavaNovice , for diamond operator operator  just change this `ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
` to this `ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
` and for the print stack trace you can just delete this line of code `e.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: When I type in a file, it does not search for it or anything, it just says "Build Successful"

Comment: This is the project I am trying to complete, if that helps solve my question about reading a file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833926/java-need-to-use-methods-and-array-lists-to-search-print-and-read-a-text-fil